# Error on db:create db:migrate with jruby and postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql, heroku, jruby

I'm trying to follow the [Getting Started with Ruby on Heroku (Microsoft Windows)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-jruby) tutorial.

On the "[Run the app locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-jruby#run-the-app-locally)" step, I am encountering an error when trying to setup the database for the demo app.

```
    C:\jruby-getting-started>jruby -S bin\rake db:create db:migrate
ArgumentProcessor.java:655:in `resolveScript': java.lang.NullPointerException
        from ArgumentProcessor.java:613:in `runBinScript'
        from ArgumentProcessor.java:303:in `processArgument'
        from ArgumentProcessor.java:105:in `processArguments'
        from ArgumentProcessor.java:98:in `processArguments'
        from RubyInstanceConfig.java:165:in `processArguments'
        from Main.java:224:in `run'
        from Main.java:197:in `main'
```

I have followed the tutorial instructions so far, including installing Postgres.  Why this error happening?  How can I resolve it?

Comment: I would recommend using cloud9 or vagrant box or some kind of virtual machine so that you can actually develop on a Unix machine. You are going to be deploying to a unix environment and getting ruby, rails and all the gems to play nice with windows might just suck up a lot of time. But then again I only use windows when somebody asks me to fix their broken computer.

Comment: I would 2nd @max's comment 100 times. Developing Ruby or Rails in Windows is one of the worst experiences I have ever had. Setting up VirtualBox, with vagrant takes ~10min. After fighting with getting versions, proper installations, etc with Rails for 5+ hours, I almost cried when my app compiled the first time on Linux. If you need help getting started, I'd be happy to walk anyone through it.

Comment: Also, please include some code to get code assistance, if you choose.

Comment: Can you post the outputs of running the command `jruby -v` and `java -version`?

Comment: It looks like maybe you are using JRuby-9.0.0.0. This is not an official release yet, and the Heroku guide doesn't support it. Make sure you are using JRuby 1.7.x

Comment: @codefinger Thanks, I had gotten the wrong jruby version, and switching to 1.7.x has resolved the problem.

Comment: max and Ian M, thank you for the suggestion.  If problems continue I may try that.

Comment: I am now using vagrant box, and would recommend this approach to anyone else running into similar problems with rails on Windows.  It is well worth the effort to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just repeating what's in the comments so this can be marked as answered.

This error results from using JRuby-9.0.0.0 with the Heroku guide. JRuby-9.0.0.0 is support on Heroku, but the guide has not adopted it yet because JRuby-9k has not had it's GA release yet.

FWIW it looks like this may be fixed in JRuby-9.0.0.0.rc2 :)